# Is there a faster way than for loops and if statements to find nearest point to another point in python?

Tags: python, performance, geopy

Is there a faster way (in Python, with a CPU) of doing the same thing as the function below? I've used `For` loops and `if` statements and wondering if there is a faster way? It currently takes about 1 minute per 100 postcodes to run this function, and I have about 70,000 to get through.

The 2 dataframes used are:

`postcode_df` which contains 71,092 rows, and columns:

- Postcode e.g. "BL4 7PD"
- Latitude e.g. 53.577653
- Longitude e.g. -2.434136

e.g.

```
postcode_df = pd.DataFrame({"Postcode":["SK12 2LH", "SK7 6LQ"],
                                    "Latitude":[53.362549, 53.373812],
                                    "Longitude":[-2.061329, -2.120956]})
```

`air` which contains 421 rows, and columns:

- TubeRef e.g. "ABC01"
- Latitude e.g. 53.55108
- Longitude e.g. -2.396236

e.g.

```
air = pd.DataFrame({"TubeRef":["Stkprt35", "Stkprt07", "Stkprt33"],
                                    "Latitude":[53.365085, 53.379502, 53.407510],
                                    "Longitude":[-2.0763, -2.120777, -2.145632]})
```

The function loops through each postcode in postcode_df, and for each postcode loops through each TubeRef and calculates (using `geopy`) the distance between them and saves the TubeRef with the shortest distance to the postcode.

The output df, `postcode_nearest_tube_refs`, contains the nearest tube per postcode and contains columns:

- Postcode e.g. "BL4 7PD"
- Nearest Air Tube e.g. "ABC01
- Distance to Air Tube KM e.g. 1.035848

```
# define function to get nearest air quality monitoring tube per postcode
def get_nearest_tubes(constituency_list):
    
    postcodes = []
    nearest_tubes = []
    distances_to_tubes = []
    
    for postcode in postcode_df["Postcode"]:
            closest_tube = ""
            shortest_dist = 500

            postcode_lat = postcode_df.loc[postcode_df["Postcode"]==postcode, "Latitude"]
            postcode_long = postcode_df.loc[postcode_df["Postcode"]==postcode, "Longitude"]
            postcode_coord = (float(postcode_lat), float(postcode_long))


            for tuberef in air["TubeRef"]:
                tube_lat = air.loc[air["TubeRef"]==tuberef, "Latitude"]
                tube_long = air.loc[air["TubeRef"]==tuberef, "Longitude"]
                tube_coord = (float(tube_lat), float(tube_long))

                # calculate distance between postcode and tube
                dist_to_tube = geopy.distance.distance(postcode_coord, tube_coord).km
                if dist_to_tube < shortest_dist:
                    shortest_dist = dist_to_tube
                    closest_tube = str(tuberef)

            # save postcode's tuberef with shortest distance
            postcodes.append(str(postcode))
            nearest_tubes.append(str(closest_tube))
            distances_to_tubes.append(shortest_dist)
            
    # create dataframe of the postcodes, nearest tuberefs and distance
    postcode_nearest_tube_refs = pd.DataFrame({"Postcode":postcodes, 
                                          "Nearest Air Tube":nearest_tubes, 
                                          "Distance to Air Tube KM": distances_to_tubes})

    return postcode_nearest_tube_refs
```

Libraries I'm using are:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
# !pip install geopy
import geopy.distance
```

Comment: updated your post with sample input and expected output

Comment: your question is still not clear see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example for how to make a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: It is called the nearest neighbor search or the post-office problem. There is a wikipedia page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nearest_neighbor_search

Comment: 700 minutes is less than 12 hours, so it should be just fine. Just don't forget to save the result afterwards

Comment: The geopandas package provide spatial indexes. [Lesson 3 of the AutoGIS 2019 course](https://automating-gis-processes.github.io/site/notebooks/L3/spatial_index.html) covers both geocoding and usage of r-trees.

Comment: Don't calculate the full distance matrix, go for the BallTree algorithm. 

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.BallTree.html

It support the haversine distance, and scales much better than full distance matrix. 

My guess is that this takes seconds/minutes. Let me know if you need a full working example. Please provide a few data lines that are panda friendly

Comment: @user3184950 (https://stackoverflow.com/users/3184950/user3184950) thanks. I've updated the question with the Pandas code for creating the input dataframes with some sample rows. Does this give you what you need? It would be great to see a full working example.

Comment: Yup- that helps. I posted it and turns out it is less than 10 seconds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An working example here, taking seconds (<10).

Import libraries

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.neighbors import BallTree
import uuid
```

I generate some random data, this takes a second as well, but at least we have some realistic amounts.

```
np_rand_post = 5 * np.random.random((72000,2))
np_rand_post = np_rand_post + np.array((53.577653, -2.434136))
```

and use UUID for fake postcodes

```
postcode_df = pd.DataFrame( np_rand_post , columns=['lat', 'long'])
postcode_df['postcode'] = [uuid.uuid4().hex[:6] for _ in range(72000)]
postcode_df.head()
```

We do the same for the air

```
np_rand = 5 * np.random.random((500,2))
np_rand = np_rand + np.array((53.55108, -2.396236))
```

and again use uuid for fake ref

```
tube_df = pd.DataFrame( np_rand , columns=['lat', 'long'])
tube_df['ref'] = [uuid.uuid4().hex[:5] for _ in range(500)]
tube_df.head()
```

extract gps values as numpy

```
postcode_gps = postcode_df[["lat", "long"]].values
air_gps = tube_df[["lat", "long"]].values
```

create a balltree

```
postal_radians =  np.radians(postcode_gps)
air_radians = np.radians(air_gps)

tree = BallTree(air_radians, leaf_size=15, metric='haversine')
```

query for closest first

```
distance, index = tree.query(postal_radians, k=1)
```

Note that the distance is not in KM, you need to convert first.

```
earth_radius = 6371000
```

```
distance_in_meters = distance * earth_radius
distance_in_meters
```

And for instance get the ref with `tube_df.ref[ index[:,0] ]`

Comment: Thanks. I'll give this a try and mark this as the answer if it works.

Comment: This worked perfectly and was almost instant it was so fast! Thank you so much!

Comment: In that case the machine is quite fast! Happy it worked thx for mark!

Answer (score 0):

You can use numpy to compute a distance matrix for any point in set A to any point in set B, then just take the point in set A that corresponds to the minimal distance.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

dfA = pd.DataFrame({'lat':np.random.uniform(0, 30, 3), 'lon':np.random.uniform(0, 30, 3), 'id':[1,2,3]})
dfB = pd.DataFrame({'lat':np.random.uniform(0, 30, 3), 'lon':np.random.uniform(0, 30, 3), 'id':['a', 'b', 'c']})
lat1 = dfA.lat.values.reshape(-1, 1)
lat2 = dfB.lat.values.reshape(1, -1)
lon1 = dfA.lon.values.reshape(-1, 1)
lon2 = dfB.lon.values.reshape(1, -1)
dists = np.sqrt((lat1 - lat2)**2 + (lon1-lon2)**2)
for id1, id2 in zip (dfB.id, dfA.id.iloc[np.argmin(dists, axis=1)]):
    print(f'the closest point in dfA to {id1} is {id2}')
```

Comment: Does this only work if dfA and dfB are the same length? I get an error "IndexError: positional indexers are out-of-bounds" trying this with my dfA that contains more rows than dfB

Comment: it does not depend on the length of A and B, you can try my solution with a different length data frame.